# How to find and replace script elements in re.compile

Tags: python, regex

I can't find all `<script>.*</script>` from the html with `re.compile`.

Here is an example from `re` document:

```
import re
result = re.findall(r'(\w+)=(\d+)', 'set width=20 and height=10')
print("type: {}, len: {}, values: {}".format(type(result), len(result), result))
print("type: {}, len: {}, values: {}".format(type(result[0]), len(result[0]), result[0]))
```

Here is the output:

```
type: <class 'list'>, len: 2, values: [('width', '20'), ('height', '10')]
type: <class 'tuple'>, len: 2, values: ('width', '20')
```

Here is my example for testing:

```
import re
string = (
    'which <script> prefix foot suffix </script> '
    'or <script> prefix hand suffix </script> fell fastest'
)

result = re.findall(r'<script>', string)
print("type: {}, len: {}, values: {}\n".format(type(result), len(result), result))

result = re.findall(r'</script>', string)
print("type: {}, len: {}, values: {}\n".format(type(result), len(result), result))

result = re.findall(r'<script>.*</script>', string)
print("type: {}, len: {}, values: {}\n".format(type(result), len(result), result))
```

Here is the output:

```
type: <class 'list'>, len: 2, values: ['<script>', '<script>']

type: <class 'list'>, len: 2, values: ['</script>', '</script>']

type: <class 'list'>, len: 1, values: ['<script> prefix foot suffix </script> or <script> prefix hand suffix </script>']
```

**Question 1:**

I want to find out all text between the `<script>` and `</script>` and included the tag itself.

Here is the expected output, the result should contains 2 items in list with value as below:

```
<script> prefix foot suffix </script>
<script> prefix hand suffix </script>
```

**Question 2:**

And then, I want to replace the matches which contains "foot" with an empty string, and then return the final html:

```
<script> prefix foot suffix </script> ----> ""
```

I have tried some patterns but no success. How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you are matching the very first `<script>` tag with the last `</script>` tag and everything in between with the greedy `.*`. What you need to do is to make it lazy by adding a `?` after it:

```
result = re.findall(r'<script>.*?</script>', string)
```

> *? matches the previous token between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy)

The `result` variable will then have  an array of the two strings. As for your question 2, you can simply loop through this array and use `re.sub` to replace the strings:

```
for r in result:
    if "foot" in r:
        r = re.sub(r'<script>(.*?)</script>', "<script></script>", r)
        print(r)
```